# check if attachment field is empty vba access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, attachment-field

I have a form with a combo box for a user to select from a range of dates. The form is based of a table where each date is a record. Each date has up to 6 attachments, each in a separate field. How can I check if an attachment field is empty when a user selects a date? I am trying to code an "On Click" event.

I also want to make it so that if a certain field lacks an attachment, then the checkbox that would normally allow a user to select that attachment will be greyed-out and say something like "No data exists for this date"

I tried doing a simple if statement

```
'Go through the recordset, testing each record to see if the date matches the selected one
'If it doesn't match, go to the next one
While Not fldDate = dteDate
    rst.MoveNext
    Wend
MsgBox fldDate

If rstPIANO.Fields("FileName") = Null Then MsgBox "No PIANO Data exists for this date"
If rstMassBalance.Value = Null Then MsgBox "No Mass Balance Data exists for this date"
If rstIR.Value = Null Then MsgBox "No IR Data exists for this date"
If rstD86.Value = Null Then MsgBox "No D86 Data exists for this date"
If rstGC.Value = Null Then MsgBox "No GC Data exists for this date"
If rstMiniGasGraphs.Value = Null Then MsgBox "No Mini Gas Graph Data exists for this date"
```

This gives me an error that says "Object invalid or no longer set"

Comment: What do you mean by "attachement" are they files on the filesystem ? rows in some table of you DB ? Your 2nd sentence ends prematurely after "separate" ... separate what ?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your recordset is called rst
you are calling it something different in each IF statement
rstPiano does not exist
use
If rst.fields("Piano") = null